# 'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Last'

Tags: c#

> `List<int>` does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no accessible extension method `Last`
> accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I getting in only one .cs files and in rest .cs file working like charm .

```
public void processImag()
{          
    _pipelineThread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_imagePipeline.Count > 0)
            {

                List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
                int MethodSyntax = numbers.Last();
                Console.WriteLine(MethodSyntax);
                //if (_imagePipeline.f.Uploaded == true)
                //{

                //}

            }

        }//while loop 
    });
    _pipelineThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: _i getting in only one .cs files and in rest .cs file working like charm_ - compare `using ` directives of working and not working files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using System.Linq

If you're in Visual Studio 2019 *(works in older versions as well)* you can see potential fixes by hovering your mouse over the not compiling code and hitting "Ctr + ."

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 8.0 you can use the "hat" operator `^` from [Ranges and Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex) to get the last index:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var lastItem = numbers[^1];  // 10
```

Otherwise, you need to add `using System.Linq;` to your using directives to use `.Last()`.